# Get WooCommerce Star Ratings in Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom template I built for my WooCommerce Shop Page that pulls in products by categories for different sections.

I need to know how I can pull the star ratings into the loop for each product. All the searching I've done for hours results in nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question. Here's how to get the star ratings in the loop.

Start by using the following code:

```
    <?php if ($average = $product->get_average_rating()) : ?>
    <?php echo '<div class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average).'"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Make sure to include the css class: woocommerce to the container, for example:

```
<ul class="woocommerce">
<li>
    <?php if ($average = $product->get_average_rating()) : ?>
    <?php echo '<div class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average).'"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</li>
</ul>
```

Furthermore, I ended changing the sizes and colors of the stars:

```
    .woocommerce {
        .star-rating {
      width: 110px !important;
      height: 30px !important;
      float: left;
      &:before {
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      span {
        &:before {
          font-size: 20px;
          color: #ffa500;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: how to get the average rating without the global variable $product. I have product id.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
global $product;
echo $product->get_rating_html();
```

Comment: get_rating_html() is depracated